# VS Code not recognizing new HTML files

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Created a new html file in VScode. However although the HTML recognizes the linked CSS file, CSS does not recognize the HTML and I am unable to add anything in CSS to further edit the class.

The new HTML is also not recognized between other HTML Files.

I saw an answer to what I thought was a similar question and played around with file.association and added the following to the JSON settings.

```
"files.associations": 
    {"*.extension": "html"},
```

This is the first time creating a HTML file through VS Code as initially I opened the folder with it all carried over from a different program.

This is the code that has been carried over from a HTML with similar code. The only difference is the class is now resetcomplete

to re-iterate I can not call the class in the CSS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>'Thank you!'</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\jacob\WebstormProjects\FormDesign\assets\stylesheet\stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="resetcomplete">
       <p>You're password has been reset! Please follow the link sent to your email address.</p>
    <form>
         <a href="form.html">Back to login screen</a><br>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

VSCode for some reason cannot format CSS when it is a separate file. If the CSS is placed within `<style>` tags in the HTML document, it should work. Because VSCode is bad with CSS natively, many opt to download a formatter extension. They can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=css%20formatter&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: Also, I've read that renaming the .css extension to .html temporarily when making changes and then changing it back afterwards, does allow the changes to stick. However, I have not tried this myself and cannot testify to its effectiveness.

Comment: Managed to get the CSS to work by using the "Changing the Extension method" which is weird. I'm not too familiar with using CSS within HTML so i'll need to start practicing that. Now the only problem is getting the HTML document to recognize the new HTML File...

Comment: Try going into user settings and adding *.html to files.associations.

Comment: sorry, that was for an older version. give me a min

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Try renaming the .html extension to .htm and see if it is recognized.

Comment: Correction again - go to file-preferences-settings under user settings > commonly used - scroll down to files:associations, and add *.html to the settings.json file. This has worked for some people.

Comment: Do not what happened but something made it work, looks like it will require more trouble shooting, going to see what happens if I start a whole project from scratch within and see if i have the same issue. Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: No prob. Glad it works! Make sure to post your solution when you finally find out what was going wrong.